# jQuery .scrollTo active header on .accordion activate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been persevering with this for a little while now, my jQuery is not great so it may be a syntax error but I am basically trying to create a mobile app function to scroll to the top of the header when an accordion body is opened. Any thoughts?

```
<script src='jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js'></script>
<script>

    $(function() {
                    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                      collapsible: true,
                      heightStyle: "content",
                      activate: $.scrollTo(ui-accordion-header-active, newHeader);
                    });
                  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI accordion [`activate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) event take a function; when it is fired you want to call your `scrollTo` function.

Your actual code is not valid because your are not referencing any jQuery object (check the console).

Try (not tested):

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            $.scrollTo(".ui-accordion-header-active", ui.newHeader);
        };
    });
});
```